# Making sql server 2008 connection with PHP with sqlsrv big problems

Tags: php, sql-server, connection

I know there are some threads with this topic, but I'm a little desperate now so I think I should do a new one. I´m trying to connect sql server 2008 with php, I'm using WAMP server and php 5.4.3. I have read a lot about the configuration of the php.ini file and I did what I needed to do. But still I can´t get my connection working!
This is a little summary of what I´ve done

1. Install the Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Native Client 64 bits in my case.
2. Download and move to php/ext folder the drivers SQLSRV30.EXE
3. Using your PHP folder, run command: "C:\PHP\php.exe" -i | more one I did that i got the next info: HP Extension Build => API(big number here) TS , VC9
4. with this information I found i need this new lines in my php.ini file

   For SQLSRV30.EXE, PHP 5.4, TS, VC9 add lines:
      [PHP_SQLSRV]
      extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
      [PHP_PDO_SQLSRV]
      extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
5. Restart my server!!

Ok so I have a page whit this code:

```
<html> 
   <head> 
   <title>Resultado</title> 
  </head> 
  <body>
     <?php
    $server='ANDRES-PC';
    $connectinfo=array("Database"=>"ejemplo");
    //connect to DB
    $db=sqlsrv_connect($server,$connectinfo);

    if($db)
    {
    echo "Connection established.<br/>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Connection couldn't be established.<br/>";
    die(print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
         ?>

    </body> 
</html>
```

But when I try to see the page I got nothing!!! Not a single word. What do you thing is my problem. I used this page http://robsphp.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/how-to-install-microsofts-sql-server.html to set up the connection!! please help

Comment: is your error display settings are on ? and can u acces db from db explorer ?

Comment: I don´t know how to do that. If you give me a little explanation I'll do it, however I wrote some echo lines in the code, and before this line  $db=sqlsrv_connect($server,$connectinfo); everything works fine, the echo instructions that I wrote after that line aren't shown.

Answer (score 0):

You've done everything correctly, so I'm guessing you have installed the 64 bit version of WAMP.  Please see this answer:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldriverforphp/thread/6dc1dc1a-5d74-415b-9225-ce11f481f301

Somewhere high up on my instructions page it says you must use 32 bit PHP:
"Microsoft's PHP driver for SQL Server only runs with PHP 32-bit builds"

Edit: never mind! I noticed your recent comment on my blog page: http://robsphp.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/how-to-install-microsofts-sql-server.html

I'll leave this answer as it's a common reason for the sqlsrv driver not loading with WAMP.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlsrv driver works only with 32-bit version of wamp. Install 32-bit version of wamp or connect to MSSQL using PDO connection with odbc driver
new PDO("odbc:dsn");